# not able to create database in android

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to create a table as well as insert some data through editText in table when a button insert is clicked.But the app stops working when i click on insert button.
This is my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:orientation="vertical"

android:text="enter here:">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter here"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="165dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Insert" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is activity.java

```
    package com.example.dailyexpenses;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    public class Entertheexpenses extends ActionBarActivity  {
   SQLiteDatabase db;
EditText et1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entertheexpenses);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    db= openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists income(expenditures number(8,2))");
     Button but1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
     {
           public void onClick(View v) 
         {   
        String name=et1.getText().toString();
        double name1 = Double.parseDouble(name);
        db.execSQL("insert into income values(name1)");   
}
     });
}
}
```

This is logcat:

```
11-07 08:13:09.630: D/AndroidRuntime(1888): Shutting down VM
11-07 08:13:09.630: W/dalvikvm(1888): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception                   (group=0xb2a6cba8)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888): Process: com.example.dailyexpenses, PID: 1888
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open       an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.dailyexpenses/databases/Mydb
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1657)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at com.example.dailyexpenses.Entertheexpenses$1.onClick(Entertheexpenses.java:52)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-07 08:13:09.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: double **name1** = Double.parseDouble(name);
        db.execSQL("insert into income values( **name1** )");

Comment: Also check your double  variable **name1** ,it is actually not being fed to the **insert** query

Comment: Are you not getting any error regarding declaring the **db** variable as **final** ?

Comment: hey please tell me how to give insert query name1.I am a beginner who is learning android as well as java.

Comment: You need to concatenate the variable in the query....I hope you know about concatenation operator..the plus sign

Comment: thanx now everything is working fine.The problem was with the insert query only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your insert query was that  value of variable `name1` was not being fed to the query,you was doing it like

```
  db.execSQL("insert into income values(name1)");
```

But you must do concatenation of the variable like following

```
  db.execSQL("insert into income values("+name1+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Database Connection before executing query:

```
if (!dbHelper.db.isOpen())
  dbHelper.open();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why to implement this check? How the database is getting closed by itself? Clarify..

Comment: you have to put this check before db.execSQL("insert into income values(name1)");

Comment: That's what I am asking? why? Error is saying that **attempt to re-open       an already-closed object:** .When this closing process happened.